# Trouble disabling the fullscreen option in a kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

So I have been writing an app using the "kivy" library, but I have an issue when setting the option to disable fullscreen. The app starts up in 800x600 resolution but the user can enable fullscreen and I don't want the user to have that option because the app does not scale good in fullscreen, it looks bad.
I have tried these options so far:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1366')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '768')
```

Setting the app to a desired resolution didn't work. Neither did this:

```
Window.fullscreen = False
```

Nor this:

```
Window.size = (900, 700)
```

And this:

```
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
```

I have done a lot of googling and spent a lot of time in kivy documentation but to no avail. All the methods I found online didn't work so now I am requesting your help. Cheers!

Comment: The `Config.set()` commands must appear at the very top of your main python script, just after `from kivy.config import Config`.

Comment: Did as you said, sadly still no effect.

Comment: Try `Config.set("graphics", "resizable", 0)`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help and time!